# Class.forName() Hive

Tags: java, jdbc, hive

I'm trying to update a Hive Driver to connect to a database.
I've downloaded the driver and I've used

```
Class.forName("org.apache.hadoop.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver");
```

to load it. It doesn't work properly and gives a `null` in return.

To be more specific, I get this message

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at HiveClient.main(HiveClient.java:39)
Java Result: 1
```

That line is `Statement stmt = con.createStatement();`

When I debug the program I realise that the problem is in Class.forName, because I've got a try-catch structure and it goes to the catch part.

```
No suitable driver found for jdbc:hive://130.206.80.46:10000/default?user=myuser&password=mypasswd
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: what gives you null? what you mean by doesn't work properly. Put your code here. Otherwise we can't help you

Comment: Have you added the driver to your classpath?

Comment: I would expect this method to throw a `ClassNotFoundException` rather than returning null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to java doc it will not give null. It will throw ClassNotFoundException if it's not able to find class in class-path. I think your are handling this exception. Make sure you have jar in classpath.

http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/h/Downloadhivejdbc0100jar.htm

Comment: Hi! I've got the driver in the classpath, but when I compile the program the driver disappears from the folder.